# How does calling the `next()` method with a value replaces the previous `yield` expression in javascript generators?

Tags: javascript, generator

This is from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next):

> `gen.next(value)`
>   The value will be assigned as a result of a `yield` expression. For example, in `variable = yield expression`, the value passed to the `.next()` function will be assigned to `variable`.

Also, this is from [Medium article](https://medium.com/dailyjs/a-simple-guide-to-understanding-javascript-es6-generators-d1c350551950):

> The second `next(10)` call, replaces the entire first `yield` expression with `10`

So my question is, how is the `next(value)` replacing the "previous" yield expression? how is it working behind the scenes. I have read about iterators but i can't understand how is `next()` working in this case.

Comment: It's...working that way because the specs say it should work that way. To understand *how* it works behind the scenes, you likely need to look at the source code for a specific engine. It's going to be implementation dependent, after all.

Comment: Generators are coroutines. `yield` and `next()` are the ways that values are sent to and from the generator.

Comment: What's hard to understand? Calling `next(value)` puts the value in some memory that the generator reads as the value of the `yield` statement. Each contains some memory for this value.

Comment: @Barmar but how is it replacing the "previous" yield exression? i thought there must be something going on behind the scenes espacially in symbol.iterator method or something?

Comment: @vikrant by working according to the spec. I really don't see the problem here - `yield` will return the next value for the iterator. So, with `x = yield 42` calling `.next()` will consume the `yield` first before doing the assignment, the *following* `.next()` resumes with assigning `x` and running to the next `yield` (if any).

Comment: @VLAZ i understand that, but i what i am not getting is when you call `yield(10)` for eg, the previous yield expression will be changed to `10`.  so how is the value we pass in yield() getting assigned to the previous expression, as you can see in the medium article i have linked in the question.

Comment: @vikrant `function* g() { a = yield 1; b = yield 2}`. Initialise it as `gen = g()`. First call is `gen.next("one")`. It returns `{ value: 1, done: false }` and *pauses* `g` before doing the assignment, so `"one"` is ignored. Then you have `gen.next("two")` it *resumes* at the assignment, makes `a = "two"` then proceeds to the next `yield`. Returns `{ value: 2, done: false }` and pauses. `gen.next("three")` assigns `b = "three"`, finishes the iterator and produces `{ value: undefined, done: true }`.

Comment: so it is working this way just because this is how it is implemented internally in javascript... i get it, i guess if i want to know how it is actually working , i would need to see the source code as you mentioned.

Comment: @vikrant Not sure what you're getting at with "previous". The `next(x)` call provides the result value of that `yield` expression that the generator is *currently* stopped at.

Comment: @Bergi yes you are indeed correct, i got the "previous" word from the medium article i have linked. also, it is kind of natural to think of the `yeild` which has already yeilded, as previous yield because it has done its job and sent the output to the next(), but it was not clear to me that it is still waiting for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a generator executes a `yield` statement

```
variable = yield value;
```

it sends `value` to the most recent caller of `next()`. Then it waits for another call to `next()`. The value passed as an argument to that call is used as the value of this `yield` expression, which is assigned to `variable`.

Then it continues with the rest of the code in the generator. The next use of `yield` repeats the above process.

It's this way because JavaScript combines sending output and receiving input into a single operation. The first input to the generator comes through the parameter list, all the future inputs come from `yield`, which gets the values from the corresponding `next()` calls. It has to send to the last `yield` because of this order of operations.

Comment: "The value passed as an argument to that call is used as the value of this yield expression", but in the MDN docs i have linked, the value is getting assigned to the previous yield expression. also, i undestand that yield will provide value when we call `next()`, but how is `next(value)` providing the value to the previous yeild?

Comment: This yield expression IS the previous yield expression, because it has been waiting for the next call to `next()`.

Comment: There's a 2-way pipe between the generator and the callers. `yield` sends to the caller, and `next(value)` sends back to the generator.

Comment: so it is just because of the javascript spec that the next(value) will pass the value to the previous yeild. i thought there was some logic related to iterators next() method.

Comment: The spec is the way it is because that's the logical order of operations. Yield sends out of the generator and waits for the next input. `next()` gets the last output and sends the next input.

Comment: " sends the next input", you mean the input to the previous yield?

Comment: Yes, because yield waits for the next input after it sends the output. The basic point is that JS combines sending the output and waiting for the next input into a single operation.

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer if the command were named `yield_and_receive`.

Comment: oh, i finally get it. thanks. you should update the answer with your last two comments, because that is where the confusion was.